# Emacs unable to locate theme engine

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I am on Ubuntu and when I run `emacs` from the terminal it seems to work fine but I get a mysterious, repetitive message displayed on my terminal:

```
(emacs:24651): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"
```

What's going on with `emacs` here and how do I stop this message from displaying?  I installed `emacs`using `get-apt` in the first place, just so you are aware.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

Comment: Installing this package fixed it.  Thanks.